# Angular: linking lazy loaded directive with DOM element

Tags: angularjs

Been reading couple blog posts about the lazy-loading in Angular:

- http://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/delay-load-anything-angular/
- http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-loading-angularjs-components-with-requirejs-after-application-bootstrap.htm
- http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/

I was able to successfully implement some of those techniques to fit my needs (AngularJS + RequireJS) for lazy-loading the controllers. However, I could not find a way to be able to truly load the directives on demand. Directives are 99.99% of times used right out of the views, so that demand has to be declared somewhere in the view. I feel that manually specifying whole list of all kinds of dependencies that each state/route depends on at the router level is quite an overkill. I might be wrong though. Expecting some arguments here.

Now, despite the uncertainty, I was thinking of having a comment directive like:

```
<!-- directive: require-directive 'translate' -->
```

Or possibly:

```
<!-- directive: require ['directive/translate', 'filter/human-readable'] ->
```

And then later in the view use it like:

```
<div translate>message.welcome<div>
```

However, this brings couple of problems:

1. Loading of directives is async and non-blocking, meaning we'll see aka-FOUT effect within the views.
2. Whole view has to be recompiled, after directive dependencies have been resolved.

So far I don't use the comment directive, and instead I have this:

```
<title require="directives/translate" translate>message.welcome</title>
```

But with this approach, you can't really benefit from the `$scope.$apply()`, I have no idea why. So instead I am forced to recompile the instance element manually with priority (to avoid the infinite loop, since otherwise `require` directive will recompile itself):

```
// note last argument 10000 — this is the priority
// @see https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#usage
$compile($element, angular.noop, 10000)($scope);priority
```

Then it works. And doesn't recompile the whole view, just the element where the `require` directive is present. Perhaps I could remove the `require` directive, right before the recompilation. Just got struck with this idea while typing the SO question. Have to give it a go.

But anyway, since we're quite deep with angular already, I'm kind of afraid to implement this code to production, because I have no real experience with priority.

So my questions:

1. Am I doing something terribly wrong? (why?)
2. Do you agree that manually writing full list of dependencies for each state/route is something unintuitive and/or redundant? (if no, why?)
3. Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

---

### EDIT # 1

Here's the **[working prototype](http://plnkr.co/edit/czCXMq?p=preview)** of the comment-based require directive:

```
<!-- directive: require ['directive/translate', 'filter/human-readable'] ->
```

However I think this method has a big flaw: we have to compile (render) whole view after dependencies resolution. One the other hand, if we sacrifice the natural directive registration:

```js
define(['app'], function() {
    app.directive('title', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        ....
    }]);
})
```

for something like:

```js
define([], function() {
    return {
        'directive': ['title', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) { ... }]]
    }
});
```

This becomes not so "native", but gives us performance boost possibilities by querying and compiling only specific DOM nodes, instead whole view. Gotta give it a go.

---

### EDIT # 2

So, inspired by idea to query elements for rendering — I gave it a go. And it works well: http://plnkr.co/edit/cClpSd?p=preview

This is still alpha and doesn't handle the filters, but it's getting close to somewhat usable look.

Comment: Interesting! I completely agree on 2. For the `can't really benefit from the $scope.$apply()`, what exactly do you mean? And could you show the code of the `require` directive?

Comment: Glad i'm not the only one. Ok, here's the working plunk of comment-based require directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/czCXMq?p=preview . Take a look at document title after `title` directive resolution and pay attention of the the first comment in the `index.html` file and note that it gets removed. As of `$scope.$apply()` note how `index` state resolves and compare it to the `require` directive. The latter can't use `$scope.$apply()` and must use `$compile()` instead. Don't know why.

Comment: Allright. I've optimised the rendering mechanism. Compile now compiles only those elements, that are use required directives. Here's the forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/cClpSd?p=preview