# Angularjs-Requirejs Directive not getting fired

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, lazy-loading

This is my issue. I want to lazy load directives using angularjs- requirejs. Below given is a sample in the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HdQMxW5MbvmY49AMz4Le

If you see, there are 3 js files. main, app and dir 
Even though all the files are loaded. dir which contains the directive does not get executed.

Main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'angular': 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            'exports': 'angular'
        }
    }
});

require(['angular', 'app'], function (angular, app) {
    console.log("Control Reaches Here. Step-1- main.js ");
    require(['dir']);
    console.log("Control Reaches Here. Step-2- main.js ");
    angular.element().ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['v2r']);
        console.log("Control Reaches here. Step-3- main.js");
    });
});
```

App.js

```
define('app', ['require', 'angular'], function (require, angular) {
    console.log('This gets loaded - app.js');
    return angular.module('v2r', []);
});
```

Dir.js

```
define('dir', ['require', 'angular', 'app'], function (require, angular, app) {
    console.log('This gets loaded - dir.js');
    app.directive('dir', function () {
        console.log("Directive fired.");
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<h1>Hello World </h1>',
            link: function (scope) {
                console.log('directive Loaded');
            }
        };
    });
    return app;
});
```

My index.html is as shown below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Lazy Loading</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.min.js" data-main="main" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <dir /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Below given is the log

-------LOGS-----------------------

--This gets loaded - app.js

--Control Reaches Here. Step-1- main.js

--Control Reaches Here. Step-2- main.js

--Control Reaches here. Step-3- main.js

--This gets loaded - dir.js

---

If you see above , the dir just gets loaded, its not executed. Could some one please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Lazy loading is not support by angularjs yet. And it isn't that strightforward to make it work. This blog might help to get started: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-loading-angularjs-components-with-requirejs-after-application-bootstrap.htm

Comment: I found a couple of examples using routing, where the directive is lazy loaded. A good one is in this http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/
I want to know if it is possible to Detect Directives from Html and then load them dynamically. Lets say using Html Parsing..

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24912936/867480